# Whither GMail's PROVIDER_CHANGED intent

Tags: android, android-intent, provider

I have been struggling to get PROVIDER_CHANGED to fire in my receiver. I am trying to detect new GMail. I know that the undocumented access to content://gmail-ls is now closed; all I need to capture is the PROVIDER_CHANGED intent, following which I can access GMail via POP/IMAP.

I can see the Intent in DDMS, as well as in CatLog, just mystified why I can see it in my app. If CatLog can see it, I should too, yes?

Here is my manifest. I have a couple of other broadcast intents (battery low etc, not shown here) that do fire OK.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>
  </intent-filter>          
</receiver>
```

And my receiver class:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    static Context context = null;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent)
    {
        context = ctxt;

        Log.d("MYAPP", intent.toString());
                    if("android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED".equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
                      ...
                    }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify android:scheme for the intent filter

Here is the update:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>
    <data android:scheme="content" />
  </intent-filter>          
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this the wrong way, take a look at the

[Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/android/)